# Apache Kafka 0.8.1.1 clean shutdown not working

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-14.04, signals, zookeeper

I have a:

- single instance of Apache Kafka (2.9.2-0.8.1.1) installed from the source, using the default configuration (`server.properties` etc.),
- Zookeeper (3.4.5+dfsg-2) stand-alone, installed from the package

..running on a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS host with a name `hostname1`.

I try to shutdown Kafka cleanly but I can't.

I tried 2 methods:

- sending SIGINT - but Kafka simply ignores it (doesn't mention recieving the signal in any log, keeps running) [SIGTERM works but that's not the point]
- using [Controlled Shutdown tool](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Replication+tools#Replicationtools-1.ControlledShutdown) - but it fails with the following..

..stacktrace:

```
[2015-02-03 12:55:49,461] ERROR Operation failed due to controller failure (kafka.admin.ShutdownBroker$)
java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: hostname1; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:369)
        at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:268)
        at kafka.admin.ShutdownBroker$.kafka$admin$ShutdownBroker$$invokeShutdown(ShutdownBroker.scala:56)
        at kafka.admin.ShutdownBroker$.main(ShutdownBroker.scala:109)
        at kafka.admin.ShutdownBroker.main(ShutdownBroker.scala)
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: hostname1; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:118)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:203)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1929)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1896)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:286)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: hostname1; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:341)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:114)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
        ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 0.8.1.1 this tool:

- does not work out of the box,
- is no longer needed.

Quote from  ["Controlled shutdown tool doesn't seem to work out of the box" Kafka JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1298):

> Do we even need this tool anymore? Currently controlled shutdown is
>   enabled through a config and automatically kicks in during a kill -15
>   of a Kafka server. I almost think we can get rid of a tool to do
>   controlled shutdown.

Here is what I ended up putting into my `config/server.properties`:

```
controlled.shutdown.enable=true
controlled.shutdown.max.retries=3
controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms=5000
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that I have used the wrong signal. I should have used SIGTERM (15) instead of SIGINT (2).

Second is that as @MaasSql have pointed out, [you have to explicitely turn on controlled shutdown in Kafka 0.8.1.1](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.1.1/core/src/main/scala/kafka/server/KafkaConfig.scala#L245).

(For 0.8.2+ you don't have do that - [it is enabled by default](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.2.0/core/src/main/scala/kafka/server/KafkaConfig.scala#L296).)